# Problem with async_write two times in a row

Tags: c++, asynchronous, networking, boost, boost-asio

When I call async_write 2 times the second message isn't sent to the server. In write handler I call async_read and when I run my code, the program is stuck on read.
In connection handler:

```
clientSocketPtr->lowest_layer().set_option(BA::ip::tcp::no_delay(true));
clientSocketPtr->set_verify_mode(BA::ssl::verify_peer);
clientSocketPtr->set_verify_callback(BA::ssl::host_name_verification(ADDRESS));
clientSocketPtr->handshake(ssl_socket::client);
//first call with first message(76 bytes)
BA::post(io_context, boost::bind(&ssd::write_msg, message, clientSocketPtr)); 
//some code here
//second call with another message(160 bytes)
BA::post(io_context, boost::bind(&ssd::write_msg, message, clientSocketPtr));
```

In write_msg:

```
void ssd::write_msg(ssd::Message &msg, ssd::ssl_socket *clientSocketPtr) {
//some code here
BA::async_write(*clientSocketPtr, BA::buffer(buf, bufSize), BA::transfer_exactly(bufSize), boost::bind(&ssd::write_handler,
BA::placeholders::error, BA::placeholders::bytes_transferred, clientSocketPtr)); 
io_context.run();
}
```

In write handler I call:

```
BA::post(io_context, boost::bind(&ssd::read_msg, clientSocketPtr));
```

And in read_msg I call async_read.

Output as text:

```
I20200818 11:17:38.633821  7417 message.hpp:53] 
Message type: 1
Message length: 70
Message: {"cli_type":"tarball","cli_version":"v2020.07.18","cmd":"cli_version"}
I20200818 11:17:38.637073  7417 sslconnection.cpp:77] Bytes sent: 76
I20200818 11:17:38.637115  7417 sslconnection.cpp:77] Bytes sent: 160
I20200818 11:17:38.640669  7417 sslconnection.cpp:109] Bytes recieved: 6
I20200818 11:17:38.640744  7417 sslconnection.cpp:122] Bytes recieved: 47
I20200818 11:17:38.640764  7417 sslconnection.cpp:128] 
Message length: 47
Message: {"cmd":"be_version","be_version":"v2020.07.15"}
```

Comment: Paste also the output from your picture to your question as text.

Comment: please provide a [mre], at a guess you are calling write on the socket whilst another write is still in progress

Comment: when I call async_write I use completion condition such as transfer_exactly(bufSize). I guess it should not start another write before previous is complete

Comment: When async_read finishes, do you start another async_read?

Comment: Calls look like this:
write_handler -> read_msg -> async_read -> read_handler -> async_read (if more then 6 bytes)
First read should be 6 bytes (msg type and msg Length) and if more than 6 bytes I call another async_read,

Comment: read_handler looks like this:
if (bytes_transfered == 6) {
msgLen = 4 last bytes;
async_read(transfer_exactly(msgLen))
}
else {
displayMsg
}

Comment: Maybe the problem is about io_context.run()? I've called it only once on the exit of entry function.

Comment: may the program be stuck after read because of io_context.run()? Played a little bit with poll() and sometimes the workflow is different but yet not expected.

Comment: [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/CPP/CppCon-2016/CppCon-2016-Michael-Caisse-Asynchronous-IO-with-BoostAsio) is one of the best investments of time I've made concerning asio. He talks about keeping things orderly with strands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some research and solved my problem using strand and making a message queue. First of all, it is important to push messages to the queue and then call the function which will check if queue isn't empty. If it isn't, the code will process the message and call `async_write` and right after this it will pop this message from message queue. In write handler code calls `async_read` and right after this it checks if the queue isn't empty again. If it isn't, it calls write function.
Some pseudo code:

```
msg_queue.push("First");
msg_queue.push("Second");
writeMsg();

writeMsg() {
    if (!msg_queue.empty()) {
    //proccess the message
    async_write(message);
    msg_queue.pop();
    } 
}

write_handler() {
    if(!error) {
        readMsg();
        if (!msg_queue.empty())
            write_msg()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can only have one `async_write` outstanding at a time. Note that `async_write` is implemented in terms of `async_write_some`, and the two writes could be interleaved.

Comment: Completion condition defends for 2 writes in the same time, isn't it?

Comment: @DronovDmitrii I don't see why it would. They will both be calling async_write_some.

Comment: How can I solve this problem? I send first message, then I expect response. Then I must send second message and I must receive response. For a moment I don't understand how to implement this, it's making me stuck.

Comment: Use a strand, or use Scatter/gather (ie. write a buffer-sequence).

Comment: I'll try tomorrow and I'll post the answer if it'll fix

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it didn't help.
Code is: 
BA::async_write(*clientSocketPtr, BA::buffer(buf, bufSize), BA::bind_executor(strand_, boost::bind(&ssd::write_handler,
    BA::placeholders::error, BA::placeholders::bytes_transferred, clientSocketPtr)));